# Closed Binary Operation over the set G

Tags: abstract-algebra

If * is a binary closed operation, associative and commutative over the set $G$ then * is also a closed operation  over the set $H = \{g \in G: g*g=g\}$

My try:

$\forall a,b,c \in G $  by hypothesis we have that:

$a*(b*c) = (a*b)*c$

$a*b = b*a$

$a*b \in G$

I have to prove that * is closed in $H$ but is also true that
* is associative and commutative in H (i already prove it).

So lets prove that

$\forall g,h \in H: g*h$ $\in H$

$g*h = (g*g)*(h*h) $  because $g,h \in H$

$= (g*h)*(g*h) $    because * is associative

i know that $(g*h) \in G$ so $ (g*h)*(g*h) \in G $  but

$= (g*h)*(g*h) = g*h $ with $g*h \in H$ so * is closed in $H$

IS THIS CORRECT???

Comment: Yes, your answer is correct, but the presentation can be improved. You have already shown that $(g*h)*(g*h) = g*h$ where $g*h \in G$, so $g*h$ is in $H$ by the definition of $H$. See my suggested answer below for reference.

Comment: I see the point!! thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
a,b \in H & \quad \Longrightarrow \quad a,b \in G \ \text{ and } \ a*a=a \ \text{ and } \ b*b=b \\
& \quad \Longrightarrow \quad a*b \in G \ \text{ and } \\ & \qquad (a*b)*(a*b) \stackrel{\rm(i)}{=} (a*(b*a))*b \stackrel{\rm(ii)}{=} (a*(a*b))*b  \stackrel{\rm(i)}{=} (a*a)*(b*b) \stackrel{\rm(iii)}{=} a*b \\
& \quad \Longrightarrow \quad a*b \in H
\end{align*}
where (i) holds by associativity, (ii) holds by commutativity, and (iii) holds because $a,b \in H$.

Comment: Correct and understood!!! Gracias!!